tensorflow_object_detection_api installation incomplete?
I need to import DetectorAPI from tensorflow_object_detection_API. But there seems to be an installation problem.
I get the no module found error, even though i just installed it.
I installed it using pip and it tells me :
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow_object_detection_api in/home/udf-pc1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.1)
(udf-pc1 is my user name)
when looking into this sit-packages folder i can find :
tensorflow_object_detection_api-0.1.1.dist-info
but not the package itself.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall,it did nothing
i tried to get it directly from the github, this made the import of tensorflow_object_detection_api possible but not the DetectorAPI class from it.
I tried on another laptop and got the same issue
Would someone have and idea please ?
Thanks a lot in advance

The last update was 5 years ago and the repository is read-only since 2022. Maybe the package just don't work anymore?

Yeah it seems like that's it
Thanks
